# Solving C++ Errors. Correct Code, Errors on VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I found a c++ program for a quiz game. I want to play a bit with it because seems a great oportunity to understand some of OOP principles.

The problem is that the program return a set of errors (that I don't have any clue how to solve) on compile. Since that is writed by some experienced programers, I think that I'm doing something wrong...

I created a pastebin with the code because is a bit to large to post it here.
I would appreciate a hint about how to get rid of those errors.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

http://pastebin.com/dgCPeHeF

I guess I'm missing a header or something, because the lines where I get the errors seems to be correct.

Comment: That piece of code has syntax error(s). And it is pretty seriously horrible to read. I'd suggest finding other examples, that's not a good one.

Comment: Also, it is using very old non-standard headers such as `dos.h` and `conio.h`. As suggested, find a more modern example. There's no point learning from something which is out of date.

Comment: `void main(void){}` isn't even valid C++

Answer (score 2):

Wow, this is really a huge file if you are just starting to learn OOP programming. I'm not sure if this is really the best way to start...

I would recommend you to build a good foundation of you programming skills first, before delving into the bloody details of such an example. You could attend an online course, e.g. at https://www.coursera.org/, or work with publicly available material, like http://htdp.org/.

There a plenty of ways to learn OOP in a more systematic matter. You will find tons of materials if you search for this topic.

Comment: Whilst this doesn't actually answer the question, it's still very helpful and is certainly a better idea than trying to imitate a poor example. +1